# Are these two settings same in maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

I want to limit maven to use only private/not public maven repository, do these two settings have the same effect ?

1.Setting mirror in settings.xml

```
<mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>my-internal-site</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <name>our maven repository</name>
            <url>http://myserver/repository</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
```

2.Setting repository in pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-internal-site</id>
      <name>our maven repository</name>
      <url>http://myserver/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Again the requirement is that maven **never** goes out to public repositories even if some dependencies are not there on the internal repository. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they don't have the same effect.

The second setting **add** a new repository as a "complement" to central but doesn't prevent Maven to check central by itself.

The first one forces Maven to use a single repository by having it mirror **all** repository requests (by setting `mirrorOf` to `*`). This is the way to use [a single repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html).

What you're looking for is thus the first setting and need to be defined in the `settings.xml`.

Now, adding your corporate repository in the `~/.m2/settings.xml` file of each machine can be a bit painful and what I like to do in a corporate environment is to distribute and install a "customized" version of Maven containing the mirror predefined in `conf/settings.xml`. This way, people just have to install the "corporate" version and they are ready to go.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent great answer Pascal

Comment: +1: That is *exactly* what I am doing: distributed a customized version of maven, with a custom `conf/settings.xml` including the `mirrorOf` directive.

Comment: I too use a custom Maven checked into SVN. Herein lies the chicken/egg problem. As a Maven purist I hate checking binary files into SVN. We could get away with checking in only the conf folder but then where will the initial Maven come from? Food for thought...

Comment: @cliff I didn't mention the how to distribute maven intentionally (at the discretion of the readers) but putting it in a VCS as part of a SCM strategy doesn't disturb me at all (and this is what I do too).

Answer (score 0):

No, they mean different things:

In the first example, you said that the given repository is a mirror of all repositories, *including the official one*.

In the second example, you simply **add** a new repository. In case a dependency is not found in the local repository, Maven will then look in this repository *after* having searched in the official repository.

Thus, to force the usage of an internal repository, you must configure the `mirror` in your `settings.xml` file.

This is explained in [the official documentation of Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html).